# Play audio file of any format in any browser

Tags: html, audio, audio-streaming, html5-audio

I am recording audio in different mobiles and each saves the file in different format like

> .m4a, .3ga, .amr

. The problem now I am facing is how to play such audio files in any browser.

```
<audio controls height="100" width="100">
  <source src="myfile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="myfile.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <embed height="50" width="100" src="myfile.mp3">
</audio>
```

I tried the above code, but not useful. because I am unable to apply the code for .m4a, .3ga and .amr.

Phone recordings wont be in mp3 files for sure

Any other approach I need to apply ?

Any suggestions ? Please

Comment: Is this question related to having multiple format options and selecting the correct one OR is it related (as I think it is) to having only an m4a or a 3ga and needing it to work in Safari, IE, Chrome, Firefox on a PC, Tablet, Mobile, etc?

Comment: @ShawnE not just 3ga or m4a, but any format audio file must get played in any browser !!

Comment: I mean it should be something generic

Comment: Then you'll need to consider either transcoding on the fly to accomodate the end client or conversion on upload to a format that will work in all browsers (such as mp3)  Both approaches do run into issues with licensing and scalability.

Comment: Use this link and you can play most of audio's using HTML5 http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am facing same problem. I tried with ffmpeg and sox for 'conversion on upload' - but didn't work with shared hosting.

Comment: @Prasoon nope.. I guess this wont be possible as there are so many formats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to bring you the bad news, but you can't play any file format in a `<audio>` HTML5 element.
Instead, you can choose from a list of valid audio formats as listed here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Shortly, the valid formats are:

1. WebM
2. Ogg
3. MP3
4. AAC
5. WAV

In your case, if you would like to play any audio format that isn't supported by the HTML5 spec, you will have to solve it, the same way audio files were played before HTML5, by using **Plugins**.
You can find on the web lots of audio-plugins for the browser, for each type of file format.